# How to split Bibiliography MLA string into BibTex using c#?

Tags: c#, string, bibtex, bibliography

I'm having a Bib String like this.

> **Baehr H.D. (1984), Thermodynamik, 5. Auflage, Springer Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg**

Now i want to split this Bibiliography string into formatted string like BibTex using C#.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.zotero.org/support/kb/importing_formatted_bibliographies for a listing of existing tools that can parse formatted bibliographic entries and extract their bibliographic information.

Comment: Hi @Rintze, Thanks for your reply. Its not giving proper results as per my requirements.Anyway this is related to my query, so i'll mark it as Answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "Its not giving proper results as per my requirements." means? Do you specifically need a solution in C#, or do the available tools fail on your example string?

Comment: I have checked each link they gave.. All of them doing the work partially..(i.e) When i give input text (as in question) to the links you referred, they are finding few fields alone.. Like Author name and year.and they cant identify the other stuff like Publisher,Location,city,country and Details about the editor...

Comment: It's not the easiest sample, since it's in German ("5. Auflage" instead of "5th edition"), and the constant use of commas also doesn't give much information which parts represent what. I don't think you'll get better results with any tool unless you start using database lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently i'm creating patterns for these structure to obtain info properly.