# Separating columns in excel using different characters as seperators

Tags: python, excel, citations, vba

I have an excel with a few thousand sources arranged in this way:

Example 1:

```
Abbott KW, Snidal D (2009) The Governance Triangle: Regulatory Standards Institutions and the Shadow of the State. In: Mattli W , Woods N (eds) The Politics of Global Regulation, pp. 44–88. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ
```

Example 2:

```
Moschella M , Tsingou E (eds) (2013) Great Expectations, Slow Transformations: Incremental Change in Financial Governance. ECPR Press, Colchester
```

I need to split them into 7 columns with this data:

1. first author
2. second author
3. third to N author
4. publication year
5. title of source article
6. published in (not always included, but always starts with In:)
7. More info - means everything after the published in/after title of source article (in case it was not part of a larger publication)

I tried using the split into columns tool in excel, but because the data is so varied I couldn't do it efficiently. 
Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: That's not an Excel file, that's plain text. Or is it? I think you need to provide more information and more examples that make use of all the "features" you've listed here. Also: Do these seven items always occur in the order you stated?

Comment: are all the authors separated from each other by commas?  What is the significance of (eds) after second author in Example 2?

Comment: the excel file has rows that look very similar to the ones I gave here. the items always occur in the same order, however sometimes item 6 is not included, and the number of authors varies. The authors are separated by commas, and eds has no significance and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this VBA macro.  It uses regular expressions to parse out the different segments; but if data is not how you have presented, it will fail; so if there are failures, you'll need to see how it mismatches either my assumptions or the way you presented the data.

The macro assumes the data starts in A1 and is in column A, with no label in row 1.  The results are written into column B and subsequent; with a label row 1 -- but these could be placed anywhere.

This code goes into a regular module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParseBiblio()
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim vBiblios() As Variant
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim re As Object, mc As Object
    Dim I As Long

'Assume Data is in column A.
'Might need to start at row 2 if there is a label row
vData = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

'Results to start in Column B with labels in row 1
Set rRes = Range("b1")

Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "(^[^,]+),?\s*([^,]+?)(?:,\s*([^(]+))?\s*\((\d{4})\)\s*(.*?\.)\s*(?:In:\s*(.*)\.)?\s*(.*)"
End With

'Results array and labels
ReDim vBiblios(1 To UBound(vData) + 1, 1 To 7)
    vBiblios(1, 1) = "First Author"
    vBiblios(1, 2) = "Second Author"
    vBiblios(1, 3) = "Other Authors"
    vBiblios(1, 4) = "Publication Year"
    vBiblios(1, 5) = "Title"
    vBiblios(1, 6) = "Published In"
    vBiblios(1, 7) = "More Info"

For I = 1 To UBound(vData)
    Set mc = re.Execute(vData(I, 1))
    If mc.Count > 0 Then
        With mc(0)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 1) = .submatches(0)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 2) = .submatches(1)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 3) = .submatches(2)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 4) = .submatches(3)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 5) = .submatches(4)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 6) = .submatches(5)
            vBiblios(I + 1, 7) = .submatches(6)
        End With
    End If
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vBiblios, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vBiblios, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vBiblios
With rRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ron! Your script works great and gives the right results, but it only runs on every odd row in the excel, and posts the results in the even rows. Can you explain to me how to fix it so that it will run on all rows and enter results on the same row as original? Thanks

Comment: So far as the results being offset from the data by one row, that is because I added a label row.  If you don't want the labels, remove that and change the index into the results array from I+1 to I (and also decrease the size of that array by one with no labels.  With regard to processing every other row, that is not the case here with the data you provided. Perhaps there is something different about your "even row" data?

Comment: the bigger problem is that the results are every other row. All rows have the same info so I don't see any differences. Is there a way I can send you a portion of the file to check if there might be an issue?

Comment: You can email it to me.  Use mocTODenilnodlefnesorTAnor after reversing the string and making the obvious substitutions.  Or post it ot a public site such as SkyDrive or Dropbox and post a link here.

Comment: The OP's file showed that the failures to match occurred when there was only a single author.  This was corrected by making the first comma optional in the regex (my answer was edited to correct that).

Answer (score 1):

See [How to split Bibiliography MLA string into BibTex using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429391/how-to-split-bibiliography-mla-string-into-bibtex-using-c/17430856#17430856) where I linked to several dedicated tools for extracting bibliographic information from formatted text.

Comment: Thanks very much! I had a look at what you posted and I think freecite is the best option for me, however I dont know what would be the best way to run it on large amount of data since I have never used ruby or perl. Can you suggest a way?

Comment: [text2bib](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/) might be easier since it spits out a BibTeX file. Do you ultimately need the bibliographic details in Excel?

Comment: And there is also [Anystyle-Parser](https://github.com/inukshuk/anystyle-parser), which is relatively new and might be a good option as well if you can find somebody to help you run it.